# nodejs spawn child process ruby prawn pdf

Tags: ruby, node.js, pdf-generation, prawn

I have the following code to spawn my Child Process in Node.  And it works great.  If i just return text it goes directly to download.  It's when i try to return the pdf that everything goes wrong.  Thanks

nodejs code

```
exports.generateReportCard = function(req,res){
  var jsonData = '{ property: abc }';
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var child = spawn('ruby', ['utilities/schedule.rb', jsonData]);
  var pdf = '';

  var chunks = [];

  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    // insert error check here...
    chunks.push(data);
  });
  child.on('close', function() {
    var pdf = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/text');
    res.send(pdf);
  });
};
```

the ruby file that is called is very very simple. but i cant seem to get the pdf binary.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'prawn'

pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
puts pdf.render_file "assignment.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to capture the standard output and send it to client as the payload. The captured contents is intended to be the PDF document, however,

```
puts pdf.render_file "assignment.pdf"
```

prints the return value of `pdf.render_file(...)` (which is `nil`) to the standard output, and you actually get nothing.

You can use the [`render`](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/Prawn/Document.html#render-instance_method) method instead, since you don't need to store the content to a file.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'prawn'

pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
pdf.render(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting me on the right path.

Here is the ruby that worked

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
puts pdf.render
```